# Angular2/nativescript: Issues importing/using Javascript module in a Typescript app

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

i'm trying to use the localstorage NativeScript module located at

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localstorage

I have a LocalStorage service coppied from a web app that I want to use with a NativeScript app, I installed the module successfully with tns plugin add nativescript-localstorage.  The first thing i'm confused about is: My app is written in Typescript and this module is written in Javascript would I be able to import/use this module in my app?  I added the following to the imports section of my LocalStorageService:  var localStorage = require('nativescript-localstorage');  The app built fine but after it got deployed I got the following error:

error:
Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-localstorage", relative to: app/tns_modules/

Then I tried:  import * as localStorage from 'nativescript-localstorage';  I then get a error saying cannot find module nativescript-localstorage.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is not related to the way you import it, rather the fact your `platforms/[platform]/[appname]/app/tns_modules` folder doesn't include the plugin. Just `tns platform remove [platform]`, `tns platform add [platform]` and `tns run [platform]` and you should see it. And be able to `require` it.

Comment: So does that folder I mentioned contain the plugin at all?

Comment: Do I need to import the localstorage module in app.module.ts? at the moment i'm just importing it in the localStorage service

Comment: If the module isn't even in you platform folder then importing it will fail as well so let's focus on that first. After adding the plugin and doing a proper build it should end up here for Android: <appfolder>/platforms/android/src/main/assets/app/tns_modules and here for iOS: <appfolder>/platforms/ios/<appname>/app/tns_modules

Comment: <appname> isn't in my platforms/android folder at all after doing a build.

Comment: I said "<appfolder>/platforms/android/src/main/assets/app/tns_module‌​s" for Android - please share a screenshot or something so we can figure this out.

Comment: Sorry I found it...  So the nativescript-localstorage module is in tns_modules...  However this is a js module which i'm trying to use in a ts project...  Should this be possible?  When I do import * as localStorage from 'nativescript-localstorage'; I get the unable to find module error before the app gets built but when I do var localStorage = require('nativescript-localstorage');  I get the same errpr at runtime...  Any idea why it would happen like that?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that (the require syntax). Also according to the readme of the plugin: https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage/blob/master/README.md#usage .. perhaps you've only used livesync and never did a `tns run android` to test it?

Comment: I usually do tns run android --geny <emulatorName> --watch.  Not sure what could be the issue at all...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort, not sure what you meant by only do a livesync but it's working perfectly now.  I still don't understand what went wrong but i'm guessing the second remove/add of the android platform did it.